# How do I reload the current page in windows phone 7.5?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm pretty new to programming C# and windows phone...

In my Windows Phone App I have a user settings page in which I want to be able to change the display language.

I'm loading a XML file to get the new text strings and assigning the textblock.Text properties from that.

I'm calling the XML file from LayoutRoot_Loaded event and when I've changed the language I want to reload the current xaml page to update the text to a new language.

Is it possible to simply reload the current XAML page?

Or are there a better way to do this?

/Thorin_M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look into Data Binding :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852595.aspx

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/04/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-one/